# Responsive Design evenly spaced boxes

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the below HTML/CSS, which is then followed by media queries in the file for the various max/min pixel sizes.

```
<div class="header-flags-wrapper">
    <div class="flagbox1">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/014-UK.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/015-spain.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/006-portugal.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/007-brazil.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flagbox2">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/002-cuba.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/003-venezuela.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/004-bolivia.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/005-paraguay.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="flagbox3">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/001-uruguay.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/008-argentina.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/009-colombia.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/010-chile.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <div class="flagbox4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/011-peru.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/012-ecuador.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://*********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/017-angola.png" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://**********.blob.core.windows.net/flags/018-european-union.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <span class="flagstretch"></span>
</div>
```

The default view on a screen 1200px wide looks good.  What I can't get my head around is how to make this responsive.  All other elements shrink closer together until they hit a boundary and then they change shape or wrap etc.  What is the best approach to achieve this please?  What I would like is that the margin on the flagboxes decreases bringing them closer together until they are touching each other then I hide the wrapper all together. Every attempt to do so has failed and like most things is probably easy when you know how.

```
.header-flags-wrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 1500px;
}

.flagbox1, .flagbox2, .flagbox3, .flagbox4 {
    width: 310px;
    /*height: 30px;*/
    /*vertical-align: top;*/
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}

.flagbox1, .flagbox2, .flagbox3, .flagbox4 a {
    float: left;
    /*width: 30px;*/
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```

Example of code can be seen at http://globaleyes.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I think you need to give us a reproducible sample of what your problem is.  Few people are going to attempt to load this code into a browser and try to test it somehow.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will do that.

Comment: Update, hope that helps.

Comment: you need media-queries. please read about them first.

Comment: I have read about them Nicholas and if you look at the CSS I have implemented them.  Whilst the other elements on the page behave as desired, I don't know what to change to make this element do the same thing. I don't need someone to do it for me, but I can't translate what I am reading into a solution that works.  A pointer in the right direction is also fine.